# ASP.NET core embedded object and concurrency exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, exception, concurrency

I am studying asp.net core using this project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-instructor-pages

I would like to add concurrency exceptions for the Instructor object, the object contains another object OfficeAssignment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

I added [Timestamp] property RowVersion for both objects. I have it working for the InstructorObject but changes to the OfficeAssignment Location property go undetected.

Below is the update code used for the postback

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id, int[] selectedCourses)
        {
            var instructor = await _context.Instructors
                .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
                .Include(i => i.CourseAssignments).ThenInclude(ca => ca.Course)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

            var officeAssignment = await _context.OfficeAssignments
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(oa => oa.InstructorId == instructor.Id);

            if (instructor == null)
            {
                return HandleNotFound(instructor);
            }
            _context.Entry(instructor).Property("RowVersion").OriginalValue = Instructor.RowVersion;
            _context.Entry(officeAssignment).Property("RowVersion").OriginalValue = Instructor.OfficeAssignment.RowVersion;

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Instructor>(
                instructor,
                "Instructor",
                i => i.LastName, i => i.FirstMidName, i => i.HireDate, i => i.OfficeAssignment))
            {
                try
                {
                    UpdateInstructorCourses(_context, selectedCourses, instructor);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var exceptionEntry in ex.Entries)
                    {
                        if (exceptionEntry.Entity is Instructor)
                        {
                            var exceptionEntity = (Instructor)exceptionEntry.Entity;
                            var databaseValues = await exceptionEntry.GetDatabaseValuesAsync();
                            if (databaseValues == null)
                            {
                                return HandleNotFound(instructor);
                            }

                            var databaseEntity = (Instructor)databaseValues.ToObject();
                            SetErrorMessage(exceptionEntity, databaseEntity);

                            Instructor.RowVersion = databaseEntity.RowVersion;
                            ModelState.Remove("Instructor.RowVersion");
                        }
                        else if (exceptionEntry.Entity is OfficeAssignment)
                        {
                            var exceptionEntity = (OfficeAssignment)exceptionEntry.Entity;
                            var databaseValues = exceptionEntry.GetDatabaseValues();
                            if (databaseValues == null)
                            {
                                return HandleNotFound(instructor);
                            }

                            var databaseEntity = (OfficeAssignment)databaseValues.ToObject();
                            SetErrorMessage(exceptionEntity, databaseEntity);

                            Instructor.OfficeAssignment.RowVersion = databaseEntity.RowVersion;
                            ModelState.Remove("Instructor.OfficeAssignment.RowVersion");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            PopulateAssignedCourseData(_context, instructor);
            return Page();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`RowVersion` is a tracking property, you need to remove the `AsNoTracking()` for your `officeAssignment`.

Besides,since you have set `RowVersion` for both models that you also need to put that original `RowVersion` property value in the OriginalValues collection for the entity.

1.Add below code on Page:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.RowVersion" />
```

Sample demo:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Instructor.ID" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Instructor.RowVersion" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.FirstMidName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.FirstMidName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.FirstMidName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.InstructorID" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.RowVersion" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

2.POST handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var instructor = await _context.Instructors
            .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ID == id);

        //modified code shown below
        var officeAssignment = await _context.OfficeAssignments
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(oa => oa.InstructorID == instructor.ID);

        _context.Entry(instructor).Property("RowVersion").OriginalValue = Instructor.RowVersion;
        _context.Entry(officeAssignment).Property("RowVersion").OriginalValue = Instructor.OfficeAssignment.RowVersion;

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Instructor>(

            instructor,

            "Instructor",

            i => i.FirstMidName, i => i.LastName,

            i => i.HireDate, i => i.OfficeAssignment))

        {
            try
            {
                UpdateInstructorCourses(_context, selectedCourses, instructor);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var exceptionEntry = ex.Entries.Single();

                if (exceptionEntry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(OfficeAssignment))
                {
                    //configure error for OfficeAssignment type
                    throw;
                }
                else
                {
                    //configure error for Instructor type
                    var exceptionEntity = (Instructor)exceptionEntry.Entity;
                    var databaseValues = await exceptionEntry.GetDatabaseValuesAsync();
                    if (databaseValues == null)
                    {
                        return HandleNotFound(instructor);
                    }

                    var databaseEntity = (Instructor)databaseValues.ToObject();
                    databaseEntity.OfficeAssignment = officeAssignment;
                    SetErorMessage(exceptionEntity, databaseEntity);

                    Instructor.RowVersion = databaseEntity.RowVersion;
                    ModelState.Remove("Instructor.RowVersion");
                }
            }


        }

        PopulateAssignedCourseData(_context, instructor);
        return Page();

    }
```

Comment: That was very helpful, got it to work now. But have one more question, if I make changes to both the Instructor and OfficeAssignments, I have to save twice. One time I see the conflict for the Instructor and the other time the conflict for the OfficeAssignment. Is there a way to combine these? I did exactly what was suggested above.

Comment: @Radjin I do not understand `I have to save twice`, the code in `catch` block is up to you

Comment: I updated the original code with the current code based on your suggestion. If there is a concurrency conflict on the Instructor object  or on the OfficeAssignment object it works perfectly. However if there is concurrency on both objects for some reason it catches the conflict on the Instructor object and then after I clicked on save it catches the conflict on the OfficeAssigment object. I do not know why this is happening, I checked the debugger there is only one error object available at the time.